# Saving invoice numbers in multitenant table raises a "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I have found an error in an invoice/orders application that needs to calculate the next concurrent invoice number for each tenant and then save the invoice.

I'm using the MySQL "FOR UPDATE" option and everything is inside a transaction and try...catch.

I have a cron job that will execute the process at specific times, BUT if user has too many cron jobs created at the SAME TIME, then I get the error and invoices are not generated/saved.

This is my first attemp (simplified) code for getting the next invoice number and saving the invoice:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($linksgweb, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

try
{
    //First I add a blank record:
    $query = "insert into mov (IDTENANT,MOVTYPE) values ($tenant,'INCOME')"; 

    if (mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query))
    {
        //Get the created record ID
        $line = mysqli_insert_id($linksgweb);

        //Now we find this record and lock it with FOR UPDATE
        $query2 = "select * from mov where IDTENANT = $tenant and MOVTYPE='INCOME' FOR UPDATE";
        if (mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query2))
        {
            //While it is locked, we get the next concurrent number
            $query3 = "select @A:=MAX(NUMBER)+1 from mov where IDTENANT = $tenant and MOVTYPE='INCOME'";
            $result=mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query3);

            $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if (($nrows==0) || ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)))
            {
                $number = "";
                if ($nrows!=0)
                    $number = $row[0];
                if ($number=="")
                    $number = 1;

                //Now I update the previously created record with that number
                $query4 = "update mov SET NUMBER = $number where IDTENANT = $tenant and ID = $line";
                mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query4)
            }
            else
            {
                $cancel=1;
                $error = 'Error: could not get the next invoice number';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $cancel=1;
            $error = 'Error: coul not edit the record';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $cancel=1;
        $error = "Error: could not create the record";
    }

    mysqli_commit($linksgweb);

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    mysqli_rollback($linksgweb);
    $cancel=1;
}
```

I'm getting the error in "couldn't edit the record" part, and the detailed error is:

**Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction**

I thought that putting it inside a transactions should force concurrent executions to wait for the previous to end, but if I create for example 20 cron jobs to execute the page at the same time (at 10:00:00), then only 3 or 4 invoices are generated, and the others fail.

Additional info: NUMBER is not an autoincrement field, as it is a multi-tenant environment, so NUMBERS can contain duplicates obviously:

```
    IDTENANT   NUMBER
   -------------------
      1          1
      1          2
      2          1
      2          2
      2          3
      3          1
```

**Edit:**

After some research, I updated my code to wait random seconds if it failed and then retry the transaction, and try at least 10 retries max.

I also changed the COMMIT / ROLLBACK position, just in case.

```
$cancel = 0;
$retries = 0;
while ($retries<10)
{
    mysqli_begin_transaction($linksgweb, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

    try {

        $query = "insert into mov (IDTENANT,MOV) values ($tenant,'INCOME')";

        if (mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query)) {

            $line = mysqli_insert_id($linksgweb);

            $query2 = "select * from mov where IDTENANT = $tenant and MOV='INCOME' FOR UPDATE";
            if (mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query2)) {

                $query3 = "select @A:=MAX(NUMBER)+1 from mov where IDTENANT = $tenant and MOV='INCOME'";
                $result = mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query3);

                $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if (($nrows == 0) || ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))) 
                {
                    $number = "";
                    if ($nrows != 0)
                        $number = $row[0];

                    if ($number == "")
                        $number = 1;

                    $query4 = "update mov SET NUMBER = " . $number . " where IDTENANT = $tenant and ID = $line";
                    if (mysqli_query($linksgweb, $query4))                    
                        $cancel = 0;                    
                    else 
                        $cancel = 1;
                    
                }
                else 
                    $cancel = 1;
                
            } 
            else 
                $cancel = 1;            
        } 
        else 
            $cancel = 1;        

        if ($cancel==0) 
            mysqli_commit($linksgweb);
        else 
            mysqli_rollback($linksgweb);

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        mysqli_rollback($linksgweb);

        $cancel = 1;
    }

    if ($cancel==1)
    {
        $retries++;
        sleep(rand(1, 5));
    }
    else
        $retries = 100;  //Force to exit the while loop

}
```

I know I can optimize redundant code. I did it this way for debugging purposes.

What I did:

- Now I do a rollback if I get an error in the query, not only in the try...catch exception (I was not getting an exception)
- I retry the transaction manually if it failed, with a while loop
- I retry the transaction 10 times (max), waiting a random number of seconds (from 1 to 5 seconds)

With this new method, I created 20 cron jobs to execute at the same excat time and all invoices were created correctly. No lock error.

Then I also created a 'stress test' to run the page 100 times in 60 seconds and all invoices were created successfully too.

However, I can't sleep peacefully yet. I need to know if there is something wrong with this code or if I should consider something else.

Answer (score 0):

- Where practical, scatter the cron jobs across multiple "minutes".  See `man 5 crontab` for some examples.  For example,  this would run something every 10 minutes, but be staggered to be at :04, :14, ... :54:

  ```
    4-59/10 * * * * foo.sh
  ```
- Be ready to replay any transaction that hits a deadlock.
- Be aware that most flavors of `INSERT` with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` will "burn" the id if the transaction is rolled back.
- Pull out of the transaction anything that you can.  That is, put it in it's own transaction, perhaps using `autocommit = 1`.  This should perhaps be the query to find the 'next' invoice id for the current customer.
- Do not use `SELECT @variable := ...`, it is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  `SET @variable := ...` and `SELECT ... INTO ...` will live on.
- I did not attempt to figure out your code; can you show just the SQL statements.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.